# Converter objeto json em array php?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Estou tentando converter um objeto `json` em `array`, já tentei de várias formas usando o `json_decode()`

```
function Save() {
    let post_id = document.getElementById('post_id');
    let pergunta = document.getElementById('pergunta');
    var dados = {
      post_id: post_id.value,
      pergunta:  pergunta.value

    };

    var data = JSON.stringify(dados);
    console.log(data);

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open('POST','index.php?class=PostForm&method=addFormPost', true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
         if (ajax.status === 200) {
             console.log(ajax.responseText);
         }
      }
    };

    ajax.send(data);
}
```

minha função é executada na ação do `click` e tenho a seguinte saída no arquivo `php`

```
array(1) {
  ["{"post_id":"8","pergunta":"55555"}"]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Que outras maneira eu poderia usar para converter ?

Comment: opa beleza ? vc ja deu uma olhada na função JSON.parse() ?
da uma olhada https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Answer (score 0):

Está enviando errado a informação para o backend e por isso não tem o resultado esperado, o correto é o seguinte:

```
var dados = `post_id=${post_id}&pergunta=${pergunta}`;
```

porque, você escolheu enviar assim com essa configuração:

```
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

o código final:

```
function Save() {
    let post_id = document.getElementById('post_id');
    let pergunta = document.getElementById('pergunta');
    var dados = `post_id=${post_id}&pergunta=${pergunta}`;
    var data = JSON.stringify(dados);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.open('POST','source.php?class=PostForm&method=addFormPost', true);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (ajax.readyState === 4) {
         if (ajax.status === 200) {
             console.log(ajax.responseText);
         }
      }
    };
    ajax.send(dados);
}
```

o seu backend retornará algo assim no formato se estiver basicamente com esse código:

```
<?php
    
    echo json_encode($_POST);
```

no retorno do Javascript:

```
{"post_id":"1","pergunta":"8"}
```

---

Existem o [fetch](https://javascript.info/fetch) ou [jQuery.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/) que torna esse tipo de operação muito mais simples, vale a pena dar uma olhada.